# Unable to get data from service using the Observable in first click

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm working on a function to get a string value from the service that I create.

**googlemap.service.ts**

[image]

**app.component.ts**

[image]

I'm trying to get the duration but the result ended up like this, It need me to click twice so that I able get the expected result.

**result**

[image]

How should I get the result just in one click.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: What do you do with travelDuration later? Use it in template or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code:

- The observable returned from `setTravelDuration` is a synchronous one, and not asynchronous. Even before `directionService.route` executes the callback, you have already returned an observable that executes immediately on subscribe.
- The `console.log('duration on map ...')` will execute synchronously and doesn't take into account the code written within subscribe.

For 2nd point you can simply move the `console.log` within subscribe i.e after `console.log('x', x)`.

For 1st point you can write the code as below:

```ts
    // within setTravelDuration method
    const directionServicePromise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      directionService.route({
        origin: origin,
        // Remaining options
      }, (res, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          // Perform some logic
          // ...
          const text = data?.duration!.text || '';
          resolve(text) // provide the value as per your use case
        } else {
          // resolve or reject as per your use case
        }
      });
    });
    
    return from(directionServicePromise);
```

Comment: but it appear the error "string | undefined" not assignable to string | PromiseLike,, i update the error on question @Siddhant

Comment: @kiku I haven't tested the code at my end as it's not shared. I have edited the answer, see if that helps. PS: I have just tried to give an example how you can implement it. You have to ensure that you pass a string to `resolve` or handle the types at other places accordingly. If you still face issues, please do share the code via stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks, it worked actually!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work the second time because you have to click twice, it works because by the time you click the second time, you got the response for the first request meanwhile and `this.travelDuration`  is now initialized.

The real issue is the console.log is outside of the subscribe callback.
You are trying to get synchronous data from an asynchronous code.

By subscribing to an async observable, it means the callback will be called when you'll get the response from your request.

As you can see, the `console.log(x, x)`is displayed in your console between the two clicks:

- clicked the first time
- a request is sent
- the second console.log is called (undefined)
- the response is received
- the inner console.log is called (initialized)